# JPA query to retrieve data using list of matching tuples as arguments

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE. Using Spring Data JPA,
I want to retrieve data from database using a list of matching tuples as arguments for jpa query. For example, My main table is Student(firstName, lastName, age, address, phoneNo) and it contains records,

1. ali, raza, 20, abc, 12345678
2. ahmad, munir, 23, def, 12121212
3. abrar, umer, 21, ghi, 87654321
4. faran, asif, 19, jkl, 85858585

Now i want to filter records based on lastName & age e.g. **(lastName, age)
 in ((raza, 20), (asif, 19))**.  in this case 1 & 4 shall be selected.

I have tried below query but not getting required results:

@Query("select s from Student s where (s.lastName, s.age) in :keys")
List findByLastNameAndAge(@Param("keys")List<> keys);

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Since JPQL "IN" does not allow MULTIPLE variables to be IN then why be surprised about that? You need to do multiple WHERE clauses to get those combinations

Comment: Really appreciate your feedback! @pvpkiran ... i must have missed it while searching but thanks to your direction, i was able to make it work using the accepted answer.